# Can we have separate tags for the new Team Foundation Build related topics not including the old XAML Build related topics to improve "findability"?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Finding anything for the new TFS build system [Team Foundation Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview) is hard. Most stuff you'll find for the [`team-build`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/team-build/info) and the [`tfsbuild`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfsbuild/info) tag is related to the old [XAML/Windows Workflow Foundation based build system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181709%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) which is completely different.

I suggest to have introduce different tags like `TF-Build` and `XAML-Build` for each topic to help us finding the right content. The tag descriptions should make clear, what build system is actually meant. I also suggest at least referencing the other tag in the tag description for those that mistakenly choose the wrong tag.

So the question is: Can we plz do that? Or, do you have a better alternative?